# Determine which USB port/RFID reader the data is coming in

Tags: python, usb, rfid

I'm using Raspberry Pi Model B+. I'm new to the RPi and I don't really know the search terms for my question.

I have four RFID readers connected to the four USB ports of my RPi. I wanted to know if there's a command in python to know which out of the four readers/USB ports the data is coming in. The RFID reader prints hex or oct number with or without carriage return upon placing an RFID card.

The closest I get is alphacharlie's answer here ([Capturing serial number of 2 USB RFID Reader in python (PI+2 RFID (Mifire RFID))](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13930/capturing-serial-number-of-2-usb-rfid-reader-in-python-pi2-rfid-mifire-rfid)) talking about /dev/input/keyboard. He/she said,

> If one of your readers is of the HID type, then you can look for the
>   input at some variation of /dev/input/keyboard

I think my reader is of the HID type, but I don't quite understand what "you can look for the input at some variation of /dev/input/keyboard"
means.

Edit: I'm using USB MIFARE™ Reader SL040A (http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/en/rfid-readers/sl040a.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the same problem with (currently) a single but different RFID USB (HIDevice) reader.  It presents a 10-digit number and a (CR +?) LF (from the tag read) as if it was typed in at a keyboard.  I made *some* headway with adding a new rule `10-local.rules` to the `/lib/udev/rules.d/` system to add a known name as a symlink in the `/dev` directory:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="end"

# Adding a standard symbolic link for RFID scanner, ideally will use to isolate from keyboard
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="vvvv", ATTRS{idProduct}=="pppp", ATTRS{serial}=="############", SYMLINK+="rfid#", TAG+="rfid", OPTIONS+=last_rule

LABEL="end"
```

In your case you will need to edit `vvvv` and `pppp` to be the vendor and product id of the readers and then copy this three more times and replace `############` with the individual serial numbers of your devices (I assume they all all the same device!) and the `#` in `rfid#` with I suggest a number from 1 to 4 or (perhaps a "_location" for each device).  Now, when each RFID USB device is plugged in it is detected and the `rfid#` symlink will appear and become available as, say `/dev/rfid1` to `/dev/rfid4` respectively.

The complication is that the input will still get treated as if it was typed at a keyboard - which will be treated as username entry on the local console as if there is a user trying to log in locally on the Pi.  Further work is needed - possibly to get the device(s) to be ignored as keyboards and have a daemon to open those devices and monitor the input...

*A (stupidly insecure) use of an RFID device (as a keyboard) as an access device:*

> As I happen to know the numbers produced by the tags I have and I only have one reader, I was able to create users with the same usernames as those numbers (`sudo adduser` can be a bit iffy about this, I think I had to use the `--force-badname` option). By disabling a password for that "user" and replacing the login shell by a shell script I could get that script to be run every time the relevant tag was presented to the reader - excerpt from in `/etc/passwd`:
>
> ```
> ...
> 1234567890:x:110:65534::/home/1234567890:/usr/local/bin/door_unlock
> ...
> ```
>
> *1234567890 is NOT the number of one of my tags...!*
>
> Whilst this works it is **not secure** - anyone getting even remote access to the Pi could try a login (via any enabled telnet/rlogin/ssh system) with the given number **and they would succeed** (no password remember!) and cause that `door_unlock` script to run.